# Trigger for data change by Excel Streaming function

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am build a streaming function with Excel add-in following this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows#create-a-streaming-asynchronous-custom-function). Everything works so far. However, I would like to change the color of the cell depending on the latest value. I am thinking about using an on-change/on-calculation trigger to color the cell every time the value is updated.

However, among all the [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events) that Excel supports, none of them works for my case. I tried `onCalculated`, which triggers when the returned value of the streaming function changes, but it does not provide me with the returned value to change the color accordingly. `onChanged` trigger's output is exactly what I am look for (it contains both the previous value and the newly returned value). However, `onChanged` does not trigger when the returned value of the streaming function changes.

I am kind of stuck. Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on my side and you are right that onChanged event does not trigger when the returned value of the streaming function changes. We'll track it on our backlog.

The Excel JavaScript API [ConditionalFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.conditionalformat?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-conditionalformat-cellvalue-member) may be a workaround.
I have verified it will be called when the returned value of the streaming function changes.
Here is a sample:

```
async function applyConditionalFormats() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    queueCommandsToClearAllConditionalFormats(sheet);

    const range = sheet.getRange("A1:E13");

    const cellValueFormat1 = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
    cellValueFormat1.cellValue.format.fill.color = "yellow";
    cellValueFormat1.cellValue.rule = { formula1: "=0", formula2: "=100", operator: "Between" };

    const cellValueFormat2 = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
    cellValueFormat2.cellValue.format.fill.color = "lightgreen";
    cellValueFormat2.cellValue.rule = { formula1: "=0", operator: "LessThan" };

    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably I should have make it clearer in my question that I want to change color depending on both before and after value (the after > before => green, else red). `onChanged` output is perfect since it provides both before and after values. I wonder whether there is a way to do conditional formatting using before and after values, instead of comparing to a fixed value?

Comment: The conditional formatting is not applicable in your case. Thanks for reporting this issue regarding unchanged event does not trigger when the returned value of the streaming function changes. It has been put on our backlog. Unfortunately, we have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: is there a public bug for this issue that I can track?

Comment: We have opened internal bug #5738632 to track it. I'll update the bug status here If it has some progress.